# About Line detection by using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I try to mark the road in the following figure, the yellow middle lines and the white edge lines.:

[image]

I use the standard code of Hough Transfrom. My code is as following:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('Road3.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


low_yellow=np.array([18, 94, 140])
up_yellow=np.array([48, 255, 255])
mask=cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, up_yellow)
edges = cv2.Canny(mask,75,150)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,50,maxLineGap=250)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),5)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But there is mistake feedback:

[image]

After changing the line with

`hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`

My output is as following:
[image]
[image]

It seems this is just part of the picture but I do not know where is the problem.

Based on Ahmet's answer, I can get the black one picture as follows but the color one is part of the whole picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), the correct way to transform RGB to HSV is using `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` flag:

```
# Convert BGR to HSV
mask = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

When you change the line, the output:

[image]

- ***How I obtain the result?***

I used `imwrite` and save image into my local pc.

```
cv2.imwrite("out.png", edges)
```

But if you want to display, first you need to resize to see the whole image.

```
cv2.imshow("edges", cv2.resize(edges, (640, 480)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After modifying, I can run the code. But my output picture is just part of the original picture. I do not know where is the problem. Please my output below the question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please restate again? Are you telling me, you have difficulty displaying the image?

Comment: Yes, I did not get the same picture as you but the left part of the picture. I put two pictures in my question. Please see it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can get your output. But the first color picture in my question is still the part of the picture but not the whole. Why the output of the black picture and color one are not consistent?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I guess is in this line:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Here the variable name is `hsv`, but the `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` would not genrate a hsv image for you. Instead it will get you a single channel Graysclae image. For HSV, you need to use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV`.