# How to detect the yellow object that obscured by shadows?

Tags: python, opencv

I try to detect the yellow line in the following picture but shadows obscured the yellow roads. Do we have any method to deal with that?

[image]

We can detect the yellow in this question:[About Line detection by using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462731/about-line-detection-by-using-opencv) and [How to delete the other object from figure by using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509388/how-to-delete-the-other-object-from-figure-by-using-opencv).

The coding is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('Road.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low_yellow = np.array([18, 94, 140])
up_yellow = np.array([48, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_yellow, up_yellow)
edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 75, 150)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, maxLineGap=250)
for line in lines:
  x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
  cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

  # cv2.imshow('image', img)
  cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", edges)
```

Comment: You have a mistake. your hsv code should be `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` not `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. You should figure out what the angle of the lines should be and filter on the line angle.

Comment: That example is easy because you don't have to deal with the shadow ...etc if you insist on using threshold then use BGR to LAB ( B)  and threshold using Otsu method.

Comment: @Ziri Sorry, could you explain more? I do not know how to set the Otsu method. Or do you mean there is a more useful method rather than HSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to convert to lab and auto-threshold
You'll have to detect the lines using a proper method.
An advanced solution would be training a dataset to do segmentation (neural network Ex : Unet )

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('YourImagePath.jpg')

cv2.imshow("Original", img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)

# Convert To lab
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# display b channel
cv2.imshow("Lab", lab[:, :, 2])
k = cv2.waitKey(0)

# auto threshold using Otsu
ret , mask = cv2.threshold(lab[:, :, 2] , 0 , 255 , cv2.THRESH_BINARY+ 
cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#display Binary
cv2.imshow("Binary", mask)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems there is still some noise about the grass in the figure. Is there any way to remove the grass?